# Problem With <> while comparing null values in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have four columns name, `Level1, Level2, Level3` and by default null values, I want to  retrieve all the rows that do not have `Level1, Level 2, Level 3` completed.

This is my my query but it is not fetching any values. Please help me

```
select name from table
where Level1 <>'Completed' and Level2 <> 'Completed and Level3 <> 'Completed'
```

Or

```
select name from table
where Level1 <>'Completed' or Level2 <> 'Completed or Level3 <> 'Completed' .
```

But it is not fetching any rows. Is there a problem with the `<>` operator or the `NULL` values?

Comment: `NULL` is not a value - it's the **absence** of a value. Therefore, you **cannot** use the regular comparison operators - `=, <>, >=, <=` with a column containing `NULL` will always be `NULL`, too (neither `true` nor `false`)

Answer (score 3):

For null values you should use `value is not null` or `value is null`

Comment: select name from table where Level1 <>'Completed'and is null or Level2 <> 'Completed and is null or Level3 <> 'Completed' and is null  . Do you wnat my query to be like this

Comment: my question is if all the three columns that is level1 , level2 ,level3 has a value 'Completed' i dont want to fetch that record.I just want to filter that record. If any one level  is 'Completed' other 2 are null or any of two levels are completed and other 1 is null . i want to fetch theser recorda also.

Comment: please help me in solving this

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to treat `NULL` "non-values" separately, try something like this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM dbo.table
WHERE ISNULL(Level1, 'null') <> 'Completed' 
  AND ISNULL(Level2, 'null') <> 'Completed'
  AND ISNULL(Level3, 'null') <> 'Completed'
```

If one of the columns is `NULL`, then that `NULL` will be replaced with whatever value you pass in as the second arugment to `ISNULL()` - and since I'm replacing a `NULL` with the 'null' string - it's not equal to `'Completed'` and will be selected.

Comment: example : name level1 level2 level3

Comment: thanks mark... When i edited my query like this it worked........ SELECT name  FROM dbo.table WHERE ISNULL(Level1, 'null') <> 'Completed'    OR ISNULL(Level2, 'null') <> 'Completed'   OR ISNULL(Level3, 'null') <> 'Completed'

Answer (score 0):

A column with a NULL means that the column value is unknown or not available.  A NULL does not equal 0 or zero length strings.

In order to filter rows based on a NULL value you have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

To find rows where any one of your columns are NULL you could use the following query:

```
Select *
From YourTable
Where Level1 Is Null Or Level2 Is Null Or Level3 Is Null
```

See this [MSDN Article for a full explanation of NULL Comparisions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196339.aspx) in MS SQL Server